# Compare 2 array and delete element

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two dynamic array like this :

```
$exclude = @()
$exclude += "GORDON"
$exclude += "DEXTER"

$servers = @()
$servers += "CEPHEE"
$servers += "FIONA"
$servers += "GORDON"
$servers += "DEXTER"
```

How can i delete element in $servers array who match with $exclude array?

And the end i want only these elements in $servers :

```
FIONA
CEPHEE
```

I don't want to use System.Collections.ArrayList

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
  $servers= Compare-Object $EXCLUDE $servers | select -expa inputobject
```

in case `$exclude` has values not in `$servers` in better use:

```
$servers = Compare-Object $servers  $exclude | ? { $_.sideindicator -eq '<=' } | 
           select -expa inputobject
```

Comment: `$servers | ? {$exclude -notcontains $_}` I like Compare-Object too.